# whenever I add passengers who survived the histogram don't show males, what's the problem?

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, data-science, data-visualization

This is the dataframe.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StM7C.png)

and this is the first code where all people died.Everything is ok.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz2zZ.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv("titanic-passengers.csv", encoding="ANSI")
data=df.head(7)
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data,col='Survived', size=3,aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.barplot,"Sex", 'Age', ci=None)
grid.add_legend
```

but whenever I add some people who survived, the male histogram disappears.why??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBKUa.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv("titanic-passengers.csv", encoding="ANSI")
data=df.head(10)
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data,col='Survived', size=3,aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.barplot,"Sex", 'Age', ci=None)
grid.add_legend
```

Comment: please paste your code in the question.

Comment: it is in the photo

Comment: And, to reproduce the scenario it is not feasible to rewrite from images. You are adding a line data=df.head(10); paste its result in your question too,. so it's quicker to copy paste and answer your question.

Comment: yes yes that's true

Comment: and for the "data=df.head(10)" it is because the dataframe is too long and i work only with 10

Comment: Have you tried using the “rows” parameter in FacetGrid? I think you are plotting over the male plot?

Comment: I want to see what is in that 'data' variable. Since, your code is correct; there is a possibility that there are no male values in the top 10 rows.

Comment: no there are .. I shared the first 10 rows in the first photo

Comment: sorry Tom, i don't get it

Comment: It looks like @Frightera has written the code detailing the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data,col='Survived', size=3,aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.barplot,"Sex", 'Age', ci=None)
```

to:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data,col='Survived', row="Sex")
grid.map(sns.barplot, 'Age', ci = None)
grid.add_legend
```